# Pseudo norm-exercice

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, topological-vector-spaces

Let $f$ be a measurable function with finite values almost everywhere. We put $$N_0(f) = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{|f|}{1 + |f|} d \mu.$$
We denoted by $L^0$ the set of measurable functions $f$ such that $N_0(f) < + \infty.$

We know that $L^0$ is a vector space  and $N_0$ is a pseudo-norm on $L^0$.

My question is: how we can prove that $L^0$ is a complete metric space?

Comment: any one can help me please

Comment: The steps are obvious: 1. A $N_0$-Cauchy sequence defines a pointwise Cauchy sequence of real numbers $\mu$-a.e. 2. The so a.e. existing limit function is measurable 3. This function is the $N_0$ limit. There should be no difficulties, go for it.